# how to add 1 minute to a given year, month, day hour minute seconds in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have this given date and time

```
2020-11-05 09:30:00
```

I wanted to add 1 minute to it. so I tried

```
select  '2020-11-05 09:30:00' + INTERVAL '1 Minute';   -- result is invalid syntax
```

I tried

```
select DATEADD(minute, 1, '2020-11-05 09:30:00'); -- result ERROR: column "minute" doesn't exist
```

so how to add 1 minute to that given date and time in my example ?

Comment: Not skilled in postgresql, but you should maybe convert `'2020-11-05 09:30:00'` into datetime with `TO_DATE` before adding with `+ interval '1 Minute'`

Comment: this one worked. thanks `TO_DATE('2020-11-05 09:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + INTERVAL '1 minute'`

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible operators named `+` that PostgreSQL considers here:

- `interval + interval`
- `date + interval`
- `timestamp without time zone + interval`
- `timestamp with time zone + interval`
- `time without time zone + interval`
- `time with time zone + interval`

Since it does not know which data type the first argument has, it follows its [data type resolution rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html) and ends up with the first one (because the arguments are of the same type). That explains the error message.

So you must be explicit about the data type of the first argument:

```
select TIMESTAMP '2020-11-05 09:30:00' + INTERVAL '1 Minute';
```